# add date to IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran, date

Let us assume a document is using the IEEEclass class as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,compsoc,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Dating IEEEtran}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Leon Meier} \IEEEauthorblockA{Nancago, USA} \and \IEEEauthorblockN{Meier Leon} \IEEEauthorblockA{Chicy, France} \thanks{This work would have been impossible without initial contributions of Abra K.\ Dabra, University of Alpha Centauri.}}
\date{2017-09-20}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}How to add a date?\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

I wish to **visibly** add a date to the paper to put a timestamp on updates and corrections. Is there a canonical way to put the date between the title and the authors or between the authors and the main text without hacking into IEEEtran.cls?

Comment: Try with documentclass options `draft`, `draftcls` or `draftclsnofoot` to see if it is ok for you

Answer (score 2):

Add `\usepackage{datetime}` in your preamble and change your title to :

```
\title{Dating IEEEtran \\\vspace*{20pt} \normalsize  \today{} (\currenttime)}
```

I don't really know if this will affect other features of IEEEtran... So just check it in your real project. (In your MWE works without problems)

**Edit:**
I also found that using: `\IEEEpubid{\today{}\space(\currenttime)}` it adds lower in the footer margin of first page a date and time that will not printed. (I know it is not what you want but may be someone will find it usefull)